# Distribution-free statistics on compact Lie groups

Tags: probability, statistics, lie-groups

Here is some background. Let $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$ be iid random variables with joint cdf $F$. Recall that the *empirical distribution function* is:
$$
F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \chi_{[-\infty,x]}(X_i) .
$$
Note that $F_n$ is a function-valued random variable. It is known that the Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic:
$$
\mathrm{KS}_n = \|F-F_n\|_\infty ,
$$
converges almost surely to zero. Even better, the normalized statistic:
$$
K_n = \sqrt{n}\cdot \mathrm{KS}_n 
$$
converges to the Kolmogorov distribution (sup of the Brownian Bridge), which doesn't depend on the distribution of the $X_i$.

> Let $G$ be a compact Lie group (semisimple, if that helps). Is there a similar statistic measuring how close a sequence in $G$ is to a given probability distribution, such that the limiting statistic is distribution-free?

Any ideas or pointers to a reference would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried CV or MO forums?

Comment: Yes: https://mathoverflow.net/q/265705